# PHP - rellenar array multidimensional

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php7, php5

Quiero construir este array multidimensional en PHP con esta salida

```
array:1 [▼
    1 => array:20 [▶],
    2 => array:30 [▶],
    3 => array:35 [▶],
]
```

Para ello tengo este código

```
    $fechas_con_entradas = [];
    $contador = 1;
    $entradas_fecha = Entradas::where('valor_id', $id)->get();

    foreach ($entradas_fecha as $entrada_fecha) {

        $fecha_compra = new \DateTime($entrada_fecha['fecha_compra']);
        $fecha_venta = new \DateTime($entrada_fecha['fecha_venta']);

        for ($i = $begin; $i <= $end; $i->modify('+1 day')) {

            if ($i->format("Y-m-d") === $fecha_compra->format("Y-m-d")) {
                $fechas_con_entradas[$contador][] = $entrada_fecha['precio_compra'];
            }
            elseif ($i->format("Y-m-d") === $fecha_venta->format("Y-m-d")) {
                $fechas_con_entradas[$contador][] = $entrada_fecha['precio_venta'];
            }
            else {
                $fechas_con_entradas[$contador][] = 'null';
            }
        }

        $contador++;
    }
```

Este código me genera lo que quiero pero solo un array de los 3, me produce esta salida

```
array:1 [▼
   1 => array:20 [▶]
   ]
```

Es como si cuando asigno $fechas_con_entradas[$contador][] esta variable contador no me la coja.

Comment: Para qué es la etiqueta `pjp`??

Comment: @Alfabravo la puse sin querer, ahora lo edito.

Comment: qué se supone que debe ir en cada array hijo del principal? Puedes mostrar los datos que hay en la tabla? No logro entender qué representa el modelo

Answer (score 0):

Para lo que quieres hacer creo que estas haciendo mal el "push" del nuevo array, yo reemplazaría:

```
$fechas_con_entradas[$contador][]= $entrada_fecha['precio_compra'];
```

por:

```
 $fechas_con_entradas[]= $entrada_fecha['precio_compra'];
```

Php almacena los arrays y le asigna un índice automáticamente sin necesidad de indicárselo como en tu caso $contador, esto lo haría si necesitas específicamente encontrar un array con ese índice.

Answer (score 0):

Tu código sí que esta produciendo el resultado que esperas. Puedes comprobarlo en [este sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3c25842fe8882ea0d2e48f9a564dca5f20660faa).

Si no es así, lo más probable es que tu variable `$entradas_fecha` sea incorrecta.

Comment: esto es mas un comentario que una respuesta mira como [responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Pudes convertirlos a `int` y recorrerlos, para cada fecha lo conviertes para comparalos

```
<?php


    $fechas_con_entradas = [];
    $entradas_fecha = [];
    $entradas_fecha[] = array(
        'fecha_compra' => '2020-10-03',
        'fecha_venta' => '2020-11-04',
        'precio_compra' => '40',
        'precio_venta' => '55'
        );
    $entradas_fecha[] =array(
        'fecha_compra' => '2020-06-04',
        'fecha_venta' => '2020-07-07',
        'precio_compra' => '45',
        'precio_venta' => '51'
        );
    $entradas_fecha[] =array(
        'fecha_compra' => '2020-08-04',
        'fecha_venta' => '2020-08-07',
        'precio_compra' => '10',
        'precio_venta' => '15'
        );

    foreach ($entradas_fecha as $entrada_fecha) {

        $fecha_compra = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($entrada_fecha['fecha_compra']));
        $fecha_venta = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($entrada_fecha['fecha_venta']));

        $begin=strtotime("01-01-2020");
        $end=strtotime("01-01-2021");
        
        $fechas = [];
        for ($i = $begin; $i <= $end; $i+=86400) {
            if (date("d-m-Y", $i) === $fecha_compra || date("d-m-Y", $i) === $fecha_venta) {
                array_push($fechas, $entrada_fecha['precio_compra'] ?? $entrada_fecha['precio_venta']);
            }
            else {
                //array_push($fechas, "null");
            }
        }
        array_push($fechas_con_entradas, $fechas);
    }
    
    print_r($fechas_con_entradas);
?>
```